# Highcharts (styledMode): filter: url(#drop-shadow not working

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts Documentation:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

"For a simple drop shadow, the built-in #drop-shadow filter can be used."

But when i try to apply filter: url(#drop-shadow) in css the highcharts-graph dissappears?

Does anyone knows how i can apply a shadow to a graph in css?

```
.highcharts-graph {
    //filter: url(#glow);
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Milenoi/nv0q568s/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that was reported here:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16147

You should wait for a response from Highcharts core developers whether it is a documentation problem or whether it will require a fix in the main Highcharts code.

Comment: Wow thank you! I did not realize that it is a nofficial bug. It is good to know thanks a lot madepiet!